# How to add a new drop down menu in top panel in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: unity, 15.10, gnome-panel

I googled but couldn't find anything.

Specifically I would like to add a new drop down menu with shell scripts as menu items.

If adding a new drop down menu is not possible,  how to add shell scripts in top menu, so that it executes on click.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you would like to do would involve creating an Appindicator. This can be done in python or in C. An example can be found here: http://conjurecode.com/create-indicator-applet-for-ubuntu-unity-with-python/

In order to run a shell script, you would need to use the subprocess module in python. In order to start using the appindicator module in python you would need to install the package python-appindicator by running `sudo apt-get install python-appindicator`: